# sql server reporting services 2005 401 error

Tags: service, reporting

I am getting the following error when trying to run reports. any thoughts or comments?

Error Message  The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

Page  ASP.testreports_aspx

Source  Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common : System.String[] GetSecureMethods()

Stack Trace  at    Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods() at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname) at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetExecutionInfo() at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters) at CFAUI.WebForms.CFAPreview.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\test\testapp\AUI\WebForms\testPreview.aspx.cs:line 31 at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

User ID

May I know if its just a configuration issue and a possible cause for the same. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Well, the 401 is clearly a permissions issue... but the code dump shows that it at least tried to run it, so it might not be the easiest one.

I'm assuming you have IIS set up with authentication for this, so that's the first thing you'll want to try: does the user account have rights to execute the ASP in that directory? Does ASP have enough rights to do whatever it needs to (e.g. create/read/delete files, access network resources, etc.)?

Comment: As you told user has access to execute ASP in that directory, because user can view a page that does nothing but when a page tries to run and render a report this happens. I will check with the deployment team and let you know on what they have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an IIS issue on the directory security for the virtual folders or parent site.

In several ways, for example, are you connecting from non-windows but Integrated Auth is set?

Comment: The user is a windows user, so any .aspx page say a test page displays correctly. But when an aspx page contains a report it does not run properly. The report is deployed in a different server. and the application is just for intranet users. Hopefully I am thinking whether the report server does not trust the webserver. But checking this configuration in that whatver server is beyond my scope. Hopefully my boss need to give some access. Thanks for your comments

Comment: it could be the webserver$ account accessing the report server, so it isn't the user's credentials being used on SSRS...